# Updating Visual Studio 2015 with Xamarin 4.2 throws error for Android Part in Xamarin forms

Tags: android, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, upgrade

I have updated Xamarin 4.2.0.680, Xamarin.Android 7.0.0.18, Xamarin.IOS 10.0.0.6 in my Visual Studio 2015 Professional edition. I am working on Xamarin Forms application. That update for specifically for iOS part to test application in iOS 10. iOS part worked. When I tried to build Android part, I received below build error for Droid project.

> The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully
>   qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the
>   directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Information from Output window,

> error C:/Program Files
>   (x86)/MSBuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets:error The
>   specified path, file name, or both are too long

Same Project is working fine in my other team member's machines. Path of solution is almost same. At same path in my system, it was working fine before upgrade.

Please help with solution.IS there any way I can find which directory or file path exceed length as from output window I do not see any path exceeds.

Comment: Hi there,

Did you find an answer to this? Its driving me nuts.

Comment: No, I had to again install Visual studio. Please make sure when you upgrade your xamarin in visual studio, update it from Xamarin Uni Installer.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce your project path length.

For example, if your project locate on c:\foo1\foo2\foo3...\fooN, you can move your project to c:\foo1 directory.

Comment: Thank you. But, it does not have length. Though, I have reduce path as much I can and still receiving error. Observation is, befiore update as same path, build was working fine and after update it gave error.